# Creating immutable instances and modifying copies in an idiomatic way

Tags: class, scala, copy, immutability, case

I would like to conditionally create copies of an object instance depending on information external to that instance.  Most of the information in the copies will be the same as the original, but some of the information will need to change.  This information is being passed around between actors, so I need the objects to be immutable in order to avoid strange concurrency-related behavior.  The following toy code is a simple example of what I would like some help with.

If I have the following code:

```
case class Container(condition:String,amount:Int,ID:Long)
```

I can do the following:

```
    val a = new Container("Hello",10,1234567890)
    println("a = " + a)
    val b = a.copy(amount = -5)
    println("b = " + b)
    println("amount in b is " + b.amount)
```

and the output is

```
a = Container(Hello,10,1234567890)
b = Container(Hello,-5,1234567890)
amount in b is -5
```

I can also conditionally create copies of the object doing the following:

```
import scala.Math._
val max = 3     
val c = if(abs(b.amount) >= max) b.copy(amount = max,condition="Goodbye") else if(abs(b.amount) < max) b.copy(amount = abs(b.amount))
println("c = " + c)
```

If I set the amount in the b object to -5, then the output is

```
c = Container(Goodbye,3,1234567890)
```

and if I set the amount in the b object to -2, then the output is

```
c = Container(Hello,2,1234567890)
```

However, when I try to print out c.amount, it gets flagged by the compiler with the following message

```
println("amount in c is " + c.amount)
```

> value amount is not a member of Any

If I change the c object creation line to

```
val c:Container = if(abs(b.amount) >= max) b.copy(amount = max,condition="Goodbye") else if(abs(b.amount) < max) b.copy(amount = abs(b.amount))
```

I get the compiler error

> type mismatch; found: Unit required:
>   Container

What is the best, idiomatic way of *conditionally* creating immutable instances of case classes by copying existing instances and modifying a value or two?

Thanks,
Bruce

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are not including a final `else` clause. Thus the type of `c` is `Any` -- the only type that is supertype both of `Container` and `Unit`, where `Unit` is the **result of not including a catch-all `else` clause**. If you try to force the result type to be `Container`, by writing `c: Container =`, the compiler now tells you the missing `else` clause resulting in `Unit` is not assignable to `Container`.

Thus

```
val c = if (abs(b.amount) >= max) {
  b.copy(amount = max, condition = "Goodbye")
} else if (abs(b.amount) < max) {
  b.copy(amount = abs(b.amount))
} else b // leave untouched !
```

works. The compiler isn't smart enough to figure out that the last `else` clause cannot be logically reached (it would need to know what `abs` and `>=` and `<` means, that they are mutual exclusive and exhaustive, and that `abs` is purely functional, as is `b.amount`).

In other words, since *you* know that the two clauses are mutually exclusive and exhaustive, you can simplify

```
val c = if (abs(b.amount) >= max) {
  b.copy(amount = max, condition = "Goodbye")
} else { // i.e. abs(b.amount) < max
  b.copy(amount = abs(b.amount))
}
```